# SQL - Select Uppercase fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

i have a table, that has a column (SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI), and has a couple of hundred rows where that column is filled in all uppercase.
I would like to know if it is possible to select all the rows that have that field in uppercase and, ultimately if i can make an update to capitalize the fields.

I'm using SQL Management Studio on MSSQL 2005

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @T TABLE
(
col VARCHAR(3) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI
)

INSERT INTO @T 
SELECT 'foo' UNION ALL SELECT 'BAR' UNION ALL SELECT ''

UPDATE @T
SET col = STUFF(LOWER(col),1,1,LEFT(col,1)) 
WHERE col = UPPER(col) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS AND LEN(col) >1

SELECT * FROM @T
```

Returns

```
(1 row(s) affected)

col
----
foo
Bar


(3 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: thanks, but i get
Invalid collation 'SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AI'

Comment: You'd need COLLATE on both sides, no?... the COLLATE here applies to the expression "UPPER(Col)" only

Comment: it worked, but do you know how i can update this table, with that where clause so i can:
set field = 'Capitalized' where field in UPPERCASE
?

Comment: @gbn - I've edited to include a test case. It seems to work OK? @Andre - What you just want the Leftmost character capitalized and the rest in lower case?

Comment: yes, that's exactly  it. i'm not understanding your query that well. Why Varchar(3)?

Comment: @Andre - Why not? You haven't provided any DDL from your end so I have no idea what your actual column types are!

Comment: @gbn - I've never had to do that. To be honest I always thought the `collate` clause applied to the `=` operation. Having just looked at the "Collation Precedence" topic in BOL an Explicit Label will take precedence over an Implicit Label which explains why it has always worked for me and why it is not needed on both sides.